# Can't install sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I know that this probably sounds like a very common question, however I have gone to the ends of the earth trying to get this thing to work. I am trying to use sympy to generate an image containing mathematical expressions however I simply can't get the library to work. I am not new to python so have gone through all the usual steps of installing libraries. I have downgraded to 3.7 (the version sympy says it is compatible with), however it still doesn't work. Doing: "pip install sympy" downloads a folder called sympy and then a python program called isympy. This isympy isn't mentioned anywhere and while I can reference it, it doesn't function properly as sympy should.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what isn't working. Is pip throwing errors? Have you looked at [SymPy's documentation on installation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/install.html)?

Comment: i get the same error on `windows10` using `vscode`.   standard `pip install sympy`.  then `import sympy` and the linter shows that `Import "sympy" could not be resolved`...  `No module named 'sympy'`....

Comment: i actually note that it works in the IDLE, but not in code editors `vscode` or `spyder`....

Answer (score 0):

Does `py -m pip install sympy` work on yours?
It prompt requirements already satisfied on mine .
Only `pip install sympy` introduced fatal error.

Comment: It just produces the same problem of not have the sympy python file